# How to align object in NSTableCellView

Tags: swift, xcode

I try to vertically position NSPopUpButton on the top in a table cell - without success. It remains centered vertically:

[image: Picture of table with "misaligned" popups]

The code that returns the NSPopUpButtons:

```
extension ViewController:NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate{


func tableViewColumnDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {…}


func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {…}


func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return tableViewData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{

    if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "value" {

        …

    } else if (tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "type") {

        let typePopUp = NSPopUpButton()

        typePopUp.addItems(withTitles:["Data", "String", "Number", "Boolean"])
        typePopUp.isBordered = false

        return typePopUp

    } else {…}
}
```

}

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Use auto resizing mask?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout in InterfaceBuilder? How are you positioning the controls?

Comment: I disabled AutoLayout but id didn't make a difference. If I apply a constraint to the popup it give me a runtime error


Error:

 [Layout] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002128fa0 NSPopUpButton:0x600003705980'Data'.height == 17   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000212a6c0 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' NSPopUpButton:0x600003705980'Data'.height == 52   (active)>"
)


Code:

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                typePopUp.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 17)
])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you subclass the table cell for that column, embed the button in an NSView, and add a "customizeCell" function to the subclass.
That function can find the actual row height of the table row when it's called from the delegate, size the view accordingly, and position the button how you like with autolayout relative to your view.

Also, while I don't think this is causing your problem, unless you left it out of your question for brevity, you aren't using "makeView."

Usually,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{
```

gets its cell from:

```
let vw = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self)
```

Cocoa builds the cell from the nib, and queues it for reuse (which probably only matters if your table is quite long)

Hope I'm on track, here.

Comment: Thanks Ron, subclassing/embedding did the trick! Working perfectly with makeView. This was exactly what I needed. Cheers, Tim